# CAT(0) space is geodesic

Tags: metric-spaces, geodesic

Proving that being CAT(0) implies being geodesic, my professor used the following fact:

If for every pair of points $x$ and $y$ in a complete metric space $X$ there exists a point $m \in X$ such that $d(x,m) = d(y,m) = d(x,y)/2$, then $X$ is a geodesic space.

I don't get how to use that m in creating the geodesic

Moreover, if such $m$ is unique, does it imply that the space is uniquely geodesic? I.e., does being CAT(0) implies being uniquely geodesic?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Although your post was very readable, I think it's still better to use  [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are studying CAT(0) spaces, or geometry of metric spaces generally, the book *A Course in Metric Geometry* by Burago, Burago, and Ivanov should (ideally)  always be in your vicinity. The statement is Theorem 2.4.16 there. Here is the proof.

Given $a,b$ at distance $L=d(a,b)$, we want an isometry $\gamma:[0,L]\to X$ such that $\gamma(0)=a$  and $\gamma(L)=b$. Note that we already have defined $\gamma$ on the subset $\{0,L\}$. Expand the definition iteratively: $\gamma(L/2)$ is a midpoint between $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(L)$, and so forth. Observe that $\gamma$ is an isometry from its domain into $X$. (Use the triangle inequality). So far we have $\gamma$ defined at all numbers of the form $kL/2^m$ with $m=0,1,2,\dots$ and $0\le k\le 2^m$. Extend to all of $[0,L]$ by Lipschitz continuity. The isometric property is preserved. So, we have a geodesic.

Also, uniqueness of midpoints implies the uniqueness of geodesics. Indeed, if midpoints are unique, then any other geodesic $\tilde \gamma$ would have to agree with our $\gamma$ at the  points $kL/2^m$, and since they are dense, we have $\tilde \gamma\equiv \gamma$.